# Can a domain registrar register any country's TLD?

Tags: domain-registrar

Are there any restrictions on what country TLD names a registrar can offer based on their country of business? Or can any domain registrar offer any TLD name considering it's available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The registrar has to have a contract with the domain registry (or an intermediary like a broker or another registrar who has a contract with the registry) for every TLD it offers. It’s not based on your country (except that some country-code registries choose to have restricted availability outside the relevant country), it’s based on contractual relationships.

Comment: And some registries require registrars to have their business in the same country, so it restrict eligibility. For other companies they need typically to be resellers of such a local registrar.